# Where to store uploaded images in Linux server using Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I have written a code to upload the images(profile picture of an student) in the server running in linux environment.The code is shown below

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/updatePhoto",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("id") String id,
                               @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               HttpServletRequest request,
                               Model model) throws IOException {
    if(!file.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            String relativePath="/resources";
            String absolutePath=request.getServletContext().getRealPath(relativePath);
            System.out.print(absolutePath);
            byte[] bytes=file.getBytes();
            File dir=new File(absolutePath);
            if(!dir.exists())
            {
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            File uploadFile=new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+id+".jpg");
            BufferedOutputStream outputStream=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(uploadFile));
            outputStream.write(bytes);
            outputStream.close();
            model.addAttribute("uploadMessage","image uploaded for id"+id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
    return "successFileUpload";

}
```

i have stored in "/resources" folder.but the problem is, whenever i generate the war file of whole application and deploy in server, it flushes the "/resources" folder and deletes the old uploaded images.Is there any way or the path ,i could upload the images.

Comment: Store them anywhere you want **except** where you're currently storing them. I.e. choose a directory which is **not** deleted every time you deploy the app, and store them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do is:

- Create a directory in the server. For example: `/myImages`
- Then grant full permissions for tomcat user

You are good to go now. I have read somewhere that you shouldn't save your stuff on `/resources` folder because it makes your app independent from container you are using: with tomcat you could use `catalina.home` but what if you shift to another container

Answer (score 1):

I store the images inside my Tomcat home location as it will be outside of my project folder(war) and inside the tomcat.

```
String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "images");
```

The above lines of code will create a folder in tomcat base directory with name 'images'.

This is the one of the best ways to store images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple way

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```